# Exception when trying to run a map of LinkedLists through a scanner

Tags: java

I have:

```
Scanner Scanner = new Scanner( myMap.get(get Object Key).get(index number)).useDelimiter(\\t);

    firstString[i] = sc.next();
    secondString[i] = sc.next();
    thirdString[i] = sc.next();
    i++;
```

This is all in a while loop. Eclipse is telling me to do `Scanner sc = new Scanner( (Readable) list.get(lc).get(i)).useDelimiter("\\t");` which I think it causing the problem. The Strings in the list are formated StringStringString.

EDIT: This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Readable
    at HashDirectory.deleteEntryByName(HashDirectory.java:218)
    at HashDirectory.main(HashDirectory.java:2332)
```

EDIT: My Method:

```
public void deleteEntry(String Entry)  {
        String[] surname= new String[count];
        String[] in= new String[count];
        String[] ext= new String[count];
        Character Ch = Entry.charAt(0);
        Character LowerCaseCh = Character.toLowerCase(Ch);
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < list.get(LowerCaseCh).size()) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner( (Readable) list.get(LowerCaseCh).get(i)).useDelimiter("\\t");
            surname[i] = sc.next();
            in[i] = sc.next();
            ext[i] = sc.next();
            i++;
        }
        if (Arrays.asList(surname).contains(Entry) == true) {
            int x = Arrays.asList(surname).indexOf(Entry);
            list.get(LowerCaseCh).remove(x);
            count--;
        }
```

Comment: please show the data structure of `myMap`

Comment: Map<Character,LinkedList> myMap= new HashMap<Character,LinkedList>();

Comment: And what is the linkedList a list of?

Comment: `list` is still magic.  We don't know what type it is or where it came from.

Comment: @Java1 Strings which are from a file. They are like String<TAB>String<TAB>String, thats why I have the "\\t"

Comment: Edited again because I left some bits, in trying to test to see if it was something wrong with the sizes of Arrays or whatever.

Comment: insert `System.out.println (list.get(LowerCaseCh).get(i));` at the top of your loop to veriy the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why use a Scanner

use `String.split` instead

```
while ( i < list.get(LowerCaseCh).size()-1) {
  String []arr = ((String)list.get(LowerCaseCh).get(i)).split ("\\t");
  surname[i] = arr[0];
  in[i] = arr[1];
  ext[i] = arr[2];
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the `Readable` cast. One, you're trying to cast a string to `Readable`, which you can't do. Two, `Scanner` can take a `String` as a constructor.

I'm still going to scold you. You should listen to your compile error. It's telling you a String cannot be cast to a Readable. It's correct. A String cannot be cast to a Readable. Yet you are casting a String to a Readable. Why? and where? To answer "where", break into muliple lines:

```
List<List<String>> l1 = list.get(LowerCaseCh);
String s = l1.get(i);
Readable r = (Readable) s; // error this line when you try to compile
Scanner scan = new Scanner( r ).useDelimiter("\\t");
```

So your compiler will tell you exactly where your error is.

Next [check the documentation for the Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It tells you there is a constructor that takes a `String`. So use that.

Comment: Scanner has a constructor for String http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String) - so why the error?

Comment: @Java1 `\\t` v. `"\\t"` as far as the question says.

Comment: Is it not something to do with the (Readable)? I never seen it in my life, just started Java.

Comment: @djechlin if I remove Readable eclipse doesn't like it and I get "The constructor Scanner(Object) is undefined" and gives me the option to Cast the argument to defined

Comment: @djechlin I added my LinkedLists to the map like myMap.put('a', new LinkedList()); so it hasn't been declared a String, do you think that is it?

Comment: @Zeb **post all your relevant code**. I'm done. Fix all your Eclipse warnings and your problem will go away.